# ACF Repeater field events triggering all together

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using this code snippet from Bootstrap:

**https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/material-card-reveal-with-image-effect**

I then created an Advanced Custom Fields repeater field to show multiple cards. The problem is, once i trigger one card, they all get triggered. Is there a way to separate the action?

Here is my code with the repeater field integrated, the CSS and JS is the same as the Bootstrap demo.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    

        <?php if( have_rows('team') ): ?>
            <?php while( have_rows('team') ): the_row(); 

                $image = get_sub_field('image');
                $position = get_sub_field('position');
                $name = get_sub_field('name');
                $bio = get_sub_field('bio');

                ?>        

                <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></div>
                        <button id="show">
                            <div class="card-content light-grey-bg center text-center">
                                <span class="card-title hind bold dark-grey text-center caps pt1"><?php echo $position; ?></span>                    
                            </div>

                            <div class="card-action blue-bg center text-center valign">
                                <p class="hind bold white caps"><?php echo $name; ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                        <div class="card-reveal">
                            <span class="card-title"><?php echo $name; ?></span>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                            <p><?php echo $bio; ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>       

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this would be to put a unique ID on the modal and accompanying trigger. They are all firing at the same time, because they all have the same trigger. You can use a count to generate the unique ID. Your javascript would also have to be in the loop (or you repeat the loop just for the JS).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">    

        <?php if( have_rows('team') ): ?>
            <?php $count = 1;?>
            <?php while( have_rows('team') ): the_row(); 

                $image = get_sub_field('image');
                $position = get_sub_field('position');
                $name = get_sub_field('name');
                $bio = get_sub_field('bio');

                ?>        

                <div class="small-12 medium-4 large-3 columns">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-image"><img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo $image; ?>"></div>
                        <button id="show<?php echo $count; ?>">
                            <div class="card-content light-grey-bg center text-center">
                                <span class="card-title hind bold dark-grey text-center caps pt1"><?php echo $position; ?></span>                    
                            </div>

                            <div class="card-action blue-bg center text-center valign">
                                <p class="hind bold white caps"><?php echo $name; ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </button>
                        <div class="card-reveal panel<?php echo $count; ?>">
                            <span class="card-title"><?php echo $name; ?></span>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
                            <p><?php echo $bio; ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
       <script>
       $(function(){

           $('#show<?php echo $count; ?>').on('click',function(){        
            $('.card-reveal panel<?php echo $count; ?>').slideToggle('slow');
           });

          $('.card-reveal panel<?php echo $count; ?> .close').on('click',function(){
            $('.card-reveal panel<?php echo $count; ?>').slideToggle('slow');
          });
       });
      </script>
               <?php $count++;  ?>  
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>       

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing's first: You are repeating this markup, so that ID of `show` is no longer unique - remove it or make it unique for each repeated item.

Now, I've added a 'show' class to your button:

```
<button type="button" class="show btn btn-custom pull-right" aria-label="Left Align">
    <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
</button>
```

And, in the JavaScript, selected that instead. I've used `closest()` and `next()` in order to `slideToggle` the `cardReveal` in the current context:

```
$(function(){
    $('.show').on('click',function(){        
        $(this).closest('.card-content').nextAll('.card-reveal').slideToggle('slow');
    });

    $('.card-reveal .close').on('click',function(){
        $(this).closest('.card-reveal').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

See it working [**here**](https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/0eVXj)